# Notation: What does $f(x) = x^{-\omega(1)}$ mean?

Tags: notation, asymptotics

I am reading a cryptography paper, and the authors introduce a function $f(x) = x^{-\omega(1)}$ and call it a negligible function in $x$. What is the possible meaning of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a relative of [big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations). We say that $f(x) = \omega(g(x))$ if $f(x) \ge k g(x)$ for all positive constants $k$, at least asymptotically.

So the notation should really be read $- \log f(x) = \omega(\log x)$, or $- \log f(x) \ge k \log x$ for every positive constant $k$ asymptotically. In other words, $f(x) \le x^{-k}$ for every positive constant $k$ asymptotically, hence $f$ vanishes faster than polynomially as $x \to \infty$.

Keep in mind that this does not define a *function* in the usual sense; rather, it specifies the asymptotic behavior of that function in a way that is good enough for whatever the paper is proving.